# how to use the values from mysql database from php in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

In php, i have used an sql query to fetch the data like :-

```
$sql="Select * from xyz";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       error_log( "id" . $row["id"]);

    }
```

Now i want to use all the values attained using $row["id"] in javascipt function and use it in a variable (var j , lets say). How to do this?

Comment: You can either `echo` the values in your JS code or transfer the values to JS script by using Ajax.

Comment: i am not able to understand how to echo "all the values" obtained from the database in javascript. I am least known to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$sql="Select * from xyz";
$errorsData = array();
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       error_log( "id" . $row["id"]);
       $errorData[]=$row["id"]
    }
$errorJson = json_encode($errorsData);

?>

<script>

   var errorJson = <?= $errorJson ?> ;

   console.log(errorJson);

<script>
```

Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir . But,The script part is not working as php is used within javascript.This is my only problem.

Comment: @akshara why is this an issue? what kind of limit do you have?

Comment: when i use it .... the code doesnt work. my perception is that .. php is server side and js is client side... that is y its not working. but if u guide me a bit.. i can  work with it sir.

Comment: there is nothing to guide you for; this is how the interaction between php an js works. php is evaluated from server and JS from browser AFTER page has been parsed by php in server. only error in this code is that this line should look like this: `   var errorJson = <?php echo $errorJson ?> ;` to work fine

Answer (score 0):

in jquery I would have done like this,

**php**

```
$sql="Select * from xyz";
$arr_json = array();
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       error_log( "id" . $row["id"]);
       $arr_json[] = $row['id'];
    }
```

echo json_encode($arr_json);

**jquery**

```
$.get(
  <THAT CALLED URL>,
  function(ret_data){
     console.log(ret_data);
     /* you can use the ret_data as ret_data.<INDEX> */
  }
);
```

Comment: Sir, Thanx for the answer but where did u referred the variable that u used in php. I am not known to jquery. can i get an explaination for what actually is done in your code.

Comment: I am just making an ajax request by saying $.get(). it actually takes 3 arguments. but 2nd arguments can be omitted here. 1st argument is url, 3rd is a function to take the data from the ajax request from the page.

Comment: in php: I am creating an array for json. storing the ids in the json array sending it back with echo json_encode(array). in the jquery I use ajax as above explained. you can use the ids as ret_data.0, ret_data.1, etc.

Comment: thanx a tonne sir. I will try with what you said :)

Comment: All the best. Try. Enjoy coding.